# Remove fields of project from lookup in set mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

Hi i have following code,

```
db.users.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            userId: 'someId',
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'images',
            let: {ID: '$userId'},
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                   $expr: {
                      $eq: ['$userId','$$ID'],
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                _id: 0,
                  flaggedImage: {
                    $cond: [{$eq: ['$isFlagged',true]},'$imageUrl',null]
                  }
                }
              },
            ],
            as: 'images',
          },
        },
        {
          $set: {
            image: {
              $filter: {
                input: '$images.flaggedImage',
                as: 'item',
                cond: {
                  $ne: ['$$item',null],
                },
              }
            },
        },
        {
          $unset: ['images'],
        },
      ]);
```

the result I am getting have 'image' field like this ....

```
"image":[
   "https://someUrl",
   null,
   null                     //i don't want this null, null. I don't know why am i getting null,null
]
```

I even tried using $first and $arrayElemAt just to return the first string from array i.e., url... but I am getting result like this

```
"image":[
  "h",
  "t",                // it just print first 3 char of url
  "t"
]
```

can anyone tell me why can't I extract just the first string, or why am I getting null, null?

**Note: When I use field name other than 'image' I get correct results.** Why am I not getting proper result when I use 'image' as field name? I want to use image field name only in set and not other name. Can anyone suggest why is this happening?

Comment: Please post an example of your starting data / collection. It's a good idea to have a playground example to work with.

Comment: That query looks like it should work.  Can you provide some sample data and/or a code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yeah it works now... my mistake... the error was due to other codes after that...